# Unfinished basement plumbing

Tags: plumbing

I was having a bathroom installed in my basement, but the person quit. I have exposed plumbing in the basement floor. How do I cover it?

Comment: If you show some pictures of the state it was left in, and describe what result you'd like to achieve (what does "cover it" mean?) you'll probably get some good advice.  Press "Edit" below your question and you can add pictures and more information.

Comment: Rubber band a trash bag around it to prevent sewer gases from coming into your home or buy a cap for it; presumably it's PVC?